# How to send jquery $.post with alert

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, list, .post

I have a problem with following script. It generates a list of places which are editable, deletable or you can even create a new one.

I want to send a $.post request when creating a new place to a php file which makes an entry into a database (MySQL) and then lists this entryes in html. Now why doesn't even the $.post send an alert message to notifi me that the data is been send?

The script isn't finished yet how you can see, but it would be great if you could give me a hand!

**JS-Script**

```
 $(function() {
      $(".edit").click(function() {
        $(this).css("display","none").prevAll(".place_name").css("display","none").prevAll(".inputfield_td").css("display","block").nextAll(".cancel").css("display","block").nextAll(".save").css("display","block").prevAll(".inputfield_td").css("display","block");
      });
      $(".cancel").click(function() {
        $(this).css("display","none").prevAll(".edit").css("display","block").prevAll(".place_name").css("display","block").prevAll(".inputfield_td").css("display","none").nextAll(".save").css("display","none");
      });
      $(".save").click(function() {
        var myvariable1 = $(this).siblings().find("input[type=text]").val();
        var myvariable2 = $(this).prevAll("td:last").attr("id");
        $(this).css("display","none").prevAll(".cancel").css("display","none").prevAll(".edit").css("display","block").prevAll(".place_name").css("display","block").prevAll(".inputfield_td").css("display","none");
        alert("save name: "+myvariable1+" save id: "+myvariable2);    
      });
      $(".delete").click(function() {
        var myvariable3 = $(this).prevAll("td:last").attr("id");
        alert(myvariable3);
      });
      $(".new").click(function() {
        var myvariable4 = $(this).prevAll("input[type=text]").val();
          $.post("place_list.php", {action: "create", name: myvariable4}, function(data){
            alert("Data Loaded: " + data);
          },"html");
        alert(myvariable4);
      });
    });
```

**PHP-File**

```
<?php
  require_once "../../includes/constants.php";
  // Connect to the database as necessary
  $dbh = mysql_connect(DB_SERVER,DB_USER,DB_PASSWORD)
    or die ("Unaable to connnect to MySQL");

  $selected = mysql_select_db(DB_NAME,$dbh)
    or die("Could not select printerweb");

    echo "<table><tbody>";
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM place");
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
      echo "<tr><td id=".$row["id"]." class=inputfield_td><input class=inputfield_place type=text value=".$row["name"]." /></td><td class=place_name>".$row["name"]."</td><td class=edit>edit</td><td class=cancel>cancel</td><td class=delete>delete</td><td class=save>SAVE</td></tr> \n";
    }
    echo "</tbody>";
    echo "</table>";
    echo "<input type=text class=inputfield_visible />";
    echo "<button class=new>New</button>";
?>
```

Comment: Have you tried to open place_list.php in your browser? Is it accessible?

Comment: Yes, tried it out and works ok.
The list gets generated into the tabed interface of jquery UI if that somehow helps you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you got firefox and firebug installed? 
If so you can view the net tab and see if the post request gets made to place_list.php and also what the response is. I suspect it is 404'ing as the path maybe incorrect. You can always use the [.ajax](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/jQuery.ajax#options) method rather than .post. This allows you to specify an error method that gets called upon a failed ajax request.

e.g

```
$.ajax({
  url : "place_list.php",
  data : {action: "create", name: myvariable4},
  cache : false,
  error : function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown){
     //console.log or alert error
     alert(errorThrown);
  },
  success: function(html){
     alert("Data Loaded: " + data);
  }
});
```

Comment: sorry but when I insert the code IE 6 crashes. I am trying to find the error. Do you maybe now where the error is in the code?

Comment: I missed a comma, try the above again and ie6 should not error

Comment: great now ie6 doesn't crash and I get two alerts once the error (which only says undefined) and the second with the content. 

Firebug says that the page the site is linking to isn't korrekt or up-to-date

Comment: odd, if you can put your site online I will have a look for you. Otherwise can you install fiddler2 which has the ability to sniff ie requests and send a screengrab of what that shows.

Comment: yep odd, now after installing netframework the request tunrs out succesfull!

How did that work?

But anyway I will tag your response as answer! 
Thank you very much for helping me ;D

Now I just have to make that the php gets my variable